# Magento2 individual URL for each website

Tags: magento2, multistore

I need to work with a Magento 2 website that haw follow structure - 
**3 websites** (b2a, b2c, b2b), and each website has **two languages** (danish, english).

So I have confingured my store view like this, so far correct right?
[image]

I have in configuration -> web -> baseurl, give each website an individual url, for example, b2c.exmpale.com, b2a.example.com, b2b.example.com. 
I have in my apache2 virtual host point all subdomains to Magento2 installation.

but when I visit these subdomains, it just show me a default apache page.
[image]

Did i do anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. I simply forgot to add **DocumentRoot** in virtual host :( ....